# Need to Remove 16.04 without damage to 14.04

Tags: 16.04

I have tried unsuccessfully to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC. I currently run 14.04, but for various reasons need to remove 16.04 and re install. How can I remove 16.04 without affecting 14.04 so that I can re install again.

Appreciate any help

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open gparted and remove the partition(s) you used to install 16.04 on to.

In gparted look at the label names. It will show 14.04 and 16.04 for the operating systems. The other partitions (if you made a /home or any other) you need to identify yourself.

From 14.04 do a `df -H` and write down the "sda" with the numbers and size of those partitions. That will make it easier to identify the 14.04 partitions for you.

Besides that: make a backup of your 14.04 personal files. If you mess up a restore is possible.